# JQuery click() event not firing when Chrome window is collapsed to mobile size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, jquery-events

I have a JQuery function like

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  //do something
}
```

This works fine when the window is large using Chrome, but yet when the window is collapsed so that the web page becomes into it's responsible mobile version, the `.click()` is not firing on the element.

How can I get it to fire and why isn't it working?

Comment: Does the element still exist?

Comment: Yes it does still exist when the screen is expanded and minimized

Comment: Do you have a `resize`  event being triggered when the page is collapsed? You can check bound events using `ev = $.data( $('body').get(0), 'events' )`

Comment: How can I check if I do?

Comment: A resize event would look like this: `$(window).on('resize', handler)`

Comment: After checking the Event Listener Breakpoints in Chrome Dev tools, yes a resize event is fired when the window is collapsed.

Comment: It's really difficult to tell without more code, but make sure there is only one instance of `#button`, also, try unbinding `$('#button').off().on('click', handler);`

Comment: As a matter of fact, doing the same thing for click, I can see a click event is fired when I click my button, however it's not reaching my code above.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how it's not reaching the event handler - if it's bound and getting fired, you're probably not capturing the response properly.

Comment: Ah I know the problem. So I actually am loading that button twice on the DOM, because when the window is large, I show one button for a large drawer, and when it's small, it loads another drawer. How can I disable the other when it's not in view so the event doesn't get directed to the wrong element?